# Laravel, redirect unregistered user to login route with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im using the Laravel base Authentication, when unregistered user attempt to access a link, for example:
http://myapp.com/financial/?email=john@web.com

It is redirect to http://myapp.com/login because the user is not registered yet.

My question is: how do i get the url parameter email of the original link (http://myapp.com/financial/?email=john@web.com) of the user tried access in my login page?

Obs: im using Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller simply try like that:

```php
$email = request()->input('email'); // null if not set

// do your things
// then redirect
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#accessing-the-request

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the URL after the redirect, you can use the `referer` header of your request. It will contain the address that was being accessed before the redirect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

> The Referer request header contains the address of the previous web
>   page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed.
>   The Referer header allows servers to identify where people are
>   visiting them from and may use that data for analytics, logging, or
>   optimized caching, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it easily by accessing `$_GET`

```
$email="";
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email'])){
   $email=$_GET['email'];
}
```

Laravel provides a function as well:

```
 $email = Input::get('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Request object like `\Request::segment(1)`
or using Input object like `Input::get('email', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Look in `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::redirectTo($request)`. You can customize this to suit your situation. ([Laravel docs for Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware)) For example:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {

        if ($request->has('email')) {
            return route('login', ['email' => $request->email]);
        } else {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```